# Rails: How to make small changes in different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to make small changes in different views?

The same partial is rendered in `index.html.erb` and `show.html.erb` as below.

index.html.erb

```
<%= render @schedules %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= render @schedules %>
```

What I'd like to do is not to display some value in the index.html.erb. (and display some value in both erb)

For example, I'd like to display `start_at` and `end_at` only in `show.html.erb` and display `title` in both erb.

_schedule.html.erb

```
<% schedule.rooms.each_with_index do |a, idx| %>

  <% a.events.each do |e| %>

    <%= l(e.start_at) %>-<%= l(e.end_at) %> # display only show.html.erb
    <%= e.title %>  #display both erb
    ...

  <% end %>

  ...
<% end %>
```

Althogh I come up with idea which I create two partials, it contradicts the DRY policy.

It would be appreciated if you could give me any idea.

Comment: How come the show action doesn't show a single `@schedule`?

Comment: You can check the current action controller if you want to differ them somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `controller.action_name`.

```
<% if controller.action_name == 'show' %>
  <%= l(e.start_at) %>-<%= l(e.end_at) %> # display only show.html.erb
<% end %>
```

The `params` hash also contains the action_name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Kris. It works! And it is easily understandable for me to use `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Can check current action and current controller on page. So we can call single partial from different actions and can customize as per action name or action and controller name.

eg.

```
<% schedule.rooms.each_with_index do |a, idx| %>

  <% a.events.each do |e| %>
    <% if @current_controller == "events" and @current_action == "show" %>
      <%= l(e.start_at) %>-<%= l(e.end_at) %> # display only show.html.erb
    <% end %>
    <%= e.title %>  #display both erb
    ...

  <% end %>

  ...
<% end %>
```

Also need to update Application Controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :instantiate_controller_and_action_names

  def instantiate_controller_and_action_names
    @current_controller = controller_name
    @current_action = action_name
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @chaitanya. I will apply `<% if controller.action_name == 'show' %>` so far. It would be appreciated if you could give me the reason your answer is good compared to this code, just for future reference.

Comment: Say that you have to render the same page in 2 different controllers. Each controller can have the same actions so adding the controller name as condition can cover more terrain.

Comment: A more advanced example, you can store the name of the controller and the action and send them through the render , that way you can check where did the render was called

Answer (score 1):

`action_name` is enough and do the trick but personally I don't like this. I'd do two separate partials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Ursus. It would be appreciated if you could give me the reason you prefer two separate partials to `action_name`, just for future reference.

Comment: It's simply a matter of tastes. Don't like these kind of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to hide/show the content based on context.

In practice, I have found this a good way to reuse partials that have small differences. Especially when those differences don't cost anything to compute i.e. printing a date

- You can cache the partials without worrying about where they are rendered
- Reduce conditional logic
- Remove duplication

`<% if controller.action_name == 'show' %>` is fine for a simple use case. If/When you come to have multiple places where the partial needs to be rendered, it will become unwieldy. The CSS solution would only require another wrapper `<div class="schedules--whatever">` and the related CSS style.

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="schedules--show">
  <%= render @schedules %> 
</div>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="schedules--index">
  <%= render @schedules %> 
</div>
```

**_schedule.html.erb**

```
<% schedule.rooms.each_with_index do |a, idx| %>
  <% a.events.each do |e| %>
    <div class="event__date">
      <%= l(e.start_at) %>-<%= l(e.end_at) %>
    </div>
    <%= e.title %>
    ...

  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

**schedules.css**

```
.schedules--show .event__date {
  display: block;
}

.schedules--index .event__date {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Rob. I will apply `<% if controller.action_name == 'show' %>` so far because of easily understandable for me to use `if` statement. It would be appreciated if you could give me the reason your answer is good compared to this code, just for future reference.

Comment: No Problem SamuraiBlue, I have updated my answer with an explanation of the differences compared to the solution @Kris provided. Happy to explain or take any feedback.